# New-AzureRmVM : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am new to Powershell, I am running following script and getting the error as mentioned in the subject line:

```
$LocationName = "West Europe"
$VNet_ResourceGroupName = "Mydeveloper_resource_group"
$VM_ResourceGroupName = "MyDeveloperResourceGroup"
$PublicIpAddress = "[]"
$PrivateIpAddress = "10.199.120.30" 
$VirtualNetworkName = "developer_vnet"
$SubnetName = "MySubnet"
$SubnetId = "/subscriptions/....../resourceGroups/developer_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/developer_vnet/subnets/MySubnet"
$VMName = "AWE4DVM022"
$VMSize = "Standard_D4s_v3"
$AllocationMethod = "Static"
$ImageId = "/subscriptions/................................./resourceGroups/MyIMAGELIBRARY/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/developer-desktop-image-...................." 

$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Type the name and password of the local administrator account."

$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name TestNIC -ResourceGroupName $VM_ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -SubnetId $SubnetId -PrivateIpAddress $PrivateIpAddress

$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize

$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Linux -ComputerName $VMName -Credential $cred

$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id 

New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VM_ResourceGroupName -ImageName $ImageId -VM $vm
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. You might want to specify your question a little: What are you trying to achieve? Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 4):

Powershell has this concept of parameter sets. When you call a script, function, or commandlet that uses parameter sets (like New-AzureRMVM does), you can't pass parameters for arguments in different sets. For example, [New-AzureRmVM has three parameters sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/new-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.1.0). `ResourceGroupName` is in parameter sets 1, 2, and 3. `ImageName` is in parameter set 1, and `VM` is in parameter set 2. Powershell can't figure out what set to use because `ImageName` is on one set while `VM` is in another.